# Switch out UserControl based on property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I switch UserControls based on a property setting in my ViewModel?

If Vm.View = "A"

```
<Window>
<local:UserControlA/>
</Window>
```

If Vm.View = "B"

```
<Window>
<local:UserControlB/>
</Window>
```

Vm.View is an enum that someday may allow for C, D, and so on. Both UserControls are bound to the same Vm, but they present the data radically different based on the user's input. So a DataTemplate based on type doesn't really work here.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`ContentControl`** inside Window and based on **`View`** value you can set it's **`ContentTemplate`** using **`DataTriggers`**.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:UserControlA/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding View}" Value="B">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:UserControlB/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: This works in so far as the controls switch, but the UserControls aren't displaying any of the vm data? I wonder why the bindings aren't working?

Comment: Yeah was about to post the same. You have to set Content to point to VM since ContentControl's template has the ContentControl's Content property as a DataContext.

Comment: @RohitVats I need this for `Pivot` element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You might leverage `DataTemplate`'s [DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and let the binding engine take care of the rest...

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="localEnums:ProduceType.Apples">
        <local:ApplesView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="localEnums:ProduceType.Oranges">
        <local:OrangesView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ProduceType}" />
    <Button Content="Change Produce" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

View Model

```
public class ProduceViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ProduceViewModel()
    {
        this.ProduceType = ProduceType.Apples;
    }

    private ProduceType _produceType;

    public ProduceType ProduceType
    {
        get
        {
            return _produceType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_produceType != value)
            {
                _produceType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Button Click Handler (Violates pure MVVM but just to demonstrate the DataTemplate switching)

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (this.DataContext as ProduceViewModel).ProduceType = ProduceType.Oranges;
    }
```